# Are there modules for managing inline images?

Tags: 7

I would like to include inline images in my posts. Is there an easy way to:

- find (and delete) unreferenced images
- find which content references a given image
- (ideally) keep things working if I decide to rename an image file
- don't show the uploaded images except where referenced manually ("Image" field seems to show all linked images below the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of searching, I believe the closest there is is the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module. It goes in the right direction on all counts, but seems to be a long way off "complete".

I haven't found any other modules that even remotely approximate what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Insert module](http://drupal.org/project/insert) along with an image field. When you using this you would hide the images in the display settings and then put whatever ones you want inside the posts. They have a recommended release for D7 as well. This really only solves putting inline images in your posts. As far as keeping track of them there really isn't much of an alternative than Media module.